# Fastest way to extract month from a series of pandas Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I have very large pandas `DataFrame` (about 70 million records) with a date column containing pandas `Timestamps`. I need the month and year from these but am finding the naive method of extracting these unworkably slow.

Here is a small example that takes about half a second on my machine. My actual problem is much larger and the timestamps are not uniformly spaced.

```
ser = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1799-01-01','2100-12-01'))

%timeit [x.month for x in ser]
#1 loops, best of 3: 558 ms per loop
```

I'm hoping there is a way to convert to a `DateTimeIndex` or something that would allow for fast extraction of the month and year that wouldn't itself take forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor for datetime-like Series:

```
ser = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1799-01-01','2100-12-01'))
print ser.dt.month
# [ 1  1  1 ..., 11 11 12]
%timeit ser.dt.month
# 100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
```

The manual looping approach:

```
%timeit [x.month for x in ser]
1 loops, best of 3: 389 ms per loop
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that 70 MI records is something you should be holding on a DataFrame. But okay, not up to me to judge your modelling.

In terms of working with time, I would convert your Datetime index to an array of  time epoch values. So you would be working with numbers now. Docs -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

I believe it would make opperation faster, but the code would be less clean, though.

Comment: I agree about the `DataFrame` being too large :)  This is one of those times when I need a quick and dirty fix but am getting a lot of the dirty with out much of the quick.

Comment: More common than it should be... Well, If time is a real concern for you, I could also suggest moving to C... Do you notice any valid difference doing what I recommended?